# Configure flutter SDK by project in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, fvm

I am using FVM (Flutter version management) with multiple projects in Android Studio.
I'd like for each android studio project to configure the flutter sdk to `<my-project-path>/.fvm/flutter_sdk` so that each project uses the right version of the flutter SDK in Android Studio

But when I go into the Android Studio's preferences and change the `Flutter SDK path` it is updated for all my projects.

Is there any way the sdk can be configured for each project independently?

Answer (score 0):

Then you start new Flutter project in Android Studio, the first screen ask you the path to Flutter SDK. Put there right path.

```
Flutter SDk path: you/path
```

As you use fvm, you need to run:

```
fvm install <VERSION>
```

in project directory. Fvm made symbolic links. You need to wait until setup is finished, then restart AS.

If you want to ignore the Flutter SDK root directory within Android Studio you can add the following to .idea/workspace.xml:

```
<component name="VcsManagerConfiguration">
  <ignored-roots>
    <path value="$PROJECT_DIR$/.fvm/flutter_sdk" />
  </ignored-roots>
</component>
```

Comment: If I do that, it configures the SDK path globally and the path for all my other projects will change. I want to set a different path for each project

Comment: In my projects I use flutter 2.x and 3.x. They are installed in: /Users/dr/Development/flutter3 and /Users/dr/Development/flutter. I have different projects with different flutter versions. Then I start new Project (File -> New -> New Flutter project) I select one of installed versions. All other projects have version which was set during project setup